# JQuery .prependTo('body') not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's midnight and I should just go to bed but I am utterly bamboozled.  I know I'm going to feel like a total egg here, but...why isn't this working??

```
var galleryPanelText = '';
galleryPanelText += '<div class="galleryPanel">';
galleryPanelText += '</div>';
alert(galleryPanelText);
galleryPanelText.prependTo('body');
alert($('.galleryPanel').length);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6kjKE/

As you can see, the first alert fires and the second doesn't, so the prepend line is breaking it.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you have is `'<div class="galleryPanel"></div>'.prependTo('body');`

Answer (score 2):

You are `prepending` **string** but **[prependTo()](http://api.jquery.com/prependto/)** needs an **jQuery object** to `prepend` like,

```
$(galleryPanelText).prependTo('body');
```

**Also** add a latest version of `jquery` see **[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6kjKE/2/)**

Comment: No dice, as far as I can see it really should just need text anyway, not an object.  EDIT: Omfg nevermind.

Answer (score 1):

(1) In your fiddle you forgot to include *jQuery*!

(2) It should be `$(galleryPanelText).prependTo('body');`

See update fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6kjKE/1/

If you notice the console of your fiddle, it would show you: *Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'prependTo'*. This would give you a hint.

If you include jQuery and run, the console wil log: *Uncaught TypeError: Object `<div class="galleryPanel"></div>` has no method 'prependTo'* which means it is expecting a jQuery object, not text.

Comment: Well don't I feel dumb.

Comment: @JS No, problems. It's midnight there and you are "bamboozled" :)